# How to iterate through an Array Value in PostForm?

Tags: go

I've been trying to read the values contained in an array sent by a Post Submit in a website.

Printing the r.PostForm data returns this map:

```
map[myArray[0].val1:[foo1] myArray[0].val2:[foo2] myArray[1].val1:[foo1] myArray[1].val2:[foo2]]
```

How can we manipulate the data? I already tried something like this:

```
func request(r http.ResponseWriter, w *http.Request){
    r.ParseForm()
    for key, array := range r.PostForm["myArray"] {
        // Do something with the val1 and val2 values.
    }
}
```

But this didn't work and I hadn't found any solution in the web.

Is possible to read an array contained in Post data using a basic solution?

Comment: I did a more deeply read about the way the data was being sent to my service, the data is following a PHP only structure using the name=myArray[index].val structure, but that cant be parsed using the http lib in golang, so I could make a parser to handle this kind of structure, or change the html, js to do it with a proper structure.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the keys of your form are `"myArray[0].val1"`, `"myArray[0].val2"`, and so on.

Try:

```
r.ParseForm()
for k, v := range r.PostForm {
    for i, value := range v {
        // Do something with the i-th value for key k.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @DrJosh9000, it seems that the problem is the structure itself, we thought that the PHP structure could be parsed with the default libraries of golang, but no, so we decided to rewrite the form that sends the data.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if you are using Gin Gonic ... `context.Request.PostForm` seems to always be an empty map[] even after calling `context.Request.ParseForm()` any familiarity with this?